# Java | How can I make one of the threads sleep while the other ones are still running?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java-threads

I'm currently working on an application which uses the draw function to animate "bouncing images" in a JPanel. To accomplish it I had to learn to use threads. When I  used them in my code someone recommended that instead of using threads directly I can use stuff like Executor framework and ExecutorService.

Right now my problem is that when adding new images I need to make sure that they don't get created inside each other. When the program detects that they would be intersecting it should wait some amount of time, while all the other threads keep running, so images are still getting moved and drawn in current positions.
What happens however is that when I make one of the threads sleep to wait for a spot to be empty the whole program seems to freeze. The only thing that seems to be running is the image moving function.

[Code in a Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/AnthonyGu55/1606a7faf693a028383c099d827acfa5)

Here is the code:

This is the BouncingImages class

```
/* NOTE: requires MyImage.java */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


import javax.swing.*;


public class BouncingImages extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BouncingImages();
    }

    static boolean imagesLoaded = true;
    JPanel resetPanel   = new JPanel();
    JPanel runningPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel pausedPanel  = new JPanel();
    JPanel btnPanel     = new JPanel();
    public static AnimationPanel animationPanel;
    ArrayList <MyImage> imageList = new ArrayList <MyImage>();
    private volatile boolean stopRequested = false; //maybe should use AtomicBoolean
    boolean isRunning = false;
    boolean isReset = true;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future f;

    //here is the part of the code responsible for creating a JFrame
    BouncingImages() {

        //set up button panel
        JButton btnStart  = new JButton("Start");
        JButton btnResume = new JButton("Resume");
        JButton btnAdd    = new JButton("Add");
        JButton btnAdd10  = new JButton("Add 10");
        JButton btnStop   = new JButton("Stop");
        JButton btnReset  = new JButton("Reset");
        JButton btnExit   = new JButton("Exit");

        btnStart.addActionListener(this);
        btnResume.addActionListener(this);
        btnAdd.addActionListener(this);
        btnAdd10.addActionListener(this);
        btnStop.addActionListener(this);
        btnReset.addActionListener(this);
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);

        resetPanel.add(btnStart);

        runningPanel.add(btnAdd);
        runningPanel.add(btnAdd10);
        runningPanel.add(btnStop);

        pausedPanel.add(btnResume);
        pausedPanel.add(btnReset);

        animationPanel = new AnimationPanel();

        resetButtons();
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(animationPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack(); //since the JPanel is controlling the size, we need pack() here.
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    //after pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    //I use different JPanels with designated buttons to make them display different buttons when the program is running, paused or completely restarted.
    public void resetButtons() {
        btnPanel.updateUI();
        if (isReset) {
            btnPanel.removeAll();
            btnPanel.add(resetPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        } else {
            if (isRunning) {
                btnPanel.removeAll();
                btnPanel.add(runningPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }
            if (!isRunning) {
                btnPanel.removeAll();
                btnPanel.add(pausedPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }
        }
    }

    //ActionListener for Buttons
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
            startAnimation();
            isRunning = true;
            isReset = false;
            resetButtons();
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Resume")) {
            startAnimation();
            isRunning = true;
            resetButtons();
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
            addImage();

        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add 10")) {
            for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
                addImage();
                startAnimation();
            }

        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
            pauseAnimation();
            isRunning = false;
            resetButtons();
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Reset")) {
            imageList.clear();
            repaint();
            isReset = true;
            resetButtons();
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    //This function starts all the animations using the Runnable AnimationThread
    void startAnimation() {
        //this starts the program
        if (f == null) {
            f = service.submit(new AnimationThread());
        }
        //this starts the program after it got paused
        else if (f.isCancelled()) {
            f = service.submit(new AnimationThread());
        }
    }
    //this pauses all the animations
    void pauseAnimation() {
        f.cancel(true);
    }

    //here is the part of the code that I have problems with. I'm not sure how to make the program wait for a spot to be empty while all the other threads are running rather than pausing them all.
    void addImage(){
        int i = 0;
        MyImage image;
        while (true) {
            image= new MyImage("image.png");
            if (checkCollision(image)) {
                if(i > 100){
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                try {
                    i++;
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            } else {
                System.out.println("image added");
                break;
            }
        }

        imageList.add(image);
    }

    //this part of the program does all the image moving. It uses the function move image from the MyImage class and a checkCollision function from this class.
    void moveAllImages() {
        for (MyImage image : imageList) {
            image.moveImage(animationPanel);
            image.calculatePoints();
            checkCollision(image);
        }
    }

    //this checks all the collisions with other images. It can be used for checking if a image can be created in some spot and also for all the bouncing callculations
    boolean checkCollision(MyImage currentImage){

        if(imageList.isEmpty()) return false;
        for(MyImage im : imageList){
            if(currentImage == im) continue;

            if(currentImage.intersects(im)){
                if(im.contains(currentImage.ml) || im.contains(currentImage.mr)){
                    currentImage.undoMove();
                    currentImage.vx = -currentImage.vx;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if(im.contains(currentImage.mt) || im.contains(currentImage.mb)){
                currentImage.undoMove();
                currentImage.vy = - currentImage.vy;
                return true;
            }

            if(currentImage.contains(im.ml) || currentImage.contains(im.mr)){
                currentImage.undoMove();
                currentImage.vx = -currentImage.vx;
                return true;
            }

            if (im.contains(currentImage.tl) || im.contains(currentImage.tr) || im.contains(currentImage.bl) || im.contains(currentImage.br)) {
                currentImage.undoMove();
                currentImage.vx *= -1;
                currentImage.vy *= -1;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }





    //This class does drawing graphics and nothing else
    public class AnimationPanel extends JPanel {

        AnimationPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) screenSize.getWidth() / 2, (int) screenSize.getHeight() / 2));
        }


        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (MyImage im : imageList) {
                g.drawImage(im.image, im.x, im.y, im.width, im.height, null);
            }
        }
    }

    //this is the Runnable AnimationThread which does all the image moving and repainting.
    private class AnimationThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!f.isCancelled()) {
                moveAllImages();
                animationPanel.repaint();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    f.cancel(true);
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the MyImage class

```
package bouncer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


//NOTE: This class requires BouncingImages.java

/* This class combines an image with a rectangle
 * which allows for easy movement and collision detection
 */
class MyImage extends Rectangle {
    //this gives it an x,y,width,height

    static int biggestDim = 0;
    BufferedImage image;
    Color color = Color.RED;
    //these are the speeds of movement
    int vx = 1;
    int vy = 1;
    int lastx = -1;
    int lasty = -1;

    Point ctr, tl, tr, bl, br, ml, mr, mt, mb;

    MyImage(String filename) {

        vx = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        vy = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);

        //load the image
        try {
            image  = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            width  = image.getWidth(null);
            height = image.getHeight(null);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: image file \"" + filename + "\" not found");
            //e.printStackTrace();
            BouncingImages.imagesLoaded = false;
            width                       = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            height                      = width - (int) (Math.random() * 70);
            color                       = Color.getHSBColor((float) Math.random(), 1.0f, 1.0f);    // a quick way to get random colours
            //System.exit(0);
        }

        //update the variable containing the biggest dimension
        if (width > biggestDim) biggestDim = width;
        if (height > biggestDim) biggestDim = height;

        calculatePoints();
    }

    void calculatePoints() {
        //Calculate points
        //corners
        tl = new Point(x, y);
        tr = new Point(x + width, y);
        bl = new Point(x, y + height);
        br = new Point(x + width, y + height);
        //center
        ctr = new Point(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
        //mid points of sides
        ml = new Point(x, y + height / 2);
        mr = new Point(x + width, y + height / 2);
        mt = new Point(x + width / 2, y);
        mb = new Point(x + width / 2, y + height);
    }

    void moveImage(BouncingImages.AnimationPanel panel) {
        lastx = x;
        lasty = y;
        x += vx;
        y += vy;
        if (x < 0 && vx < 0) {
            x  = 0;
            vx = -vx;
        }
        if (y < 0 && vy < 0) {
            y  = 0;
            vy = -vy;
        }
        if (x + width > panel.getWidth() && vx > 0) {
            x  = panel.getWidth() - width;
            vx = -vx;
        }
        if (y + height > panel.getHeight() && vy > 0) {
            y  = panel.getHeight() - height;
            vy = -vy;
        }
    }

    void undoMove() {
        if (lastx > 0) {
            x = lastx;
            y = lasty;
        }
        lastx = lasty = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the main thread in method `addImage` in `Thread.sleep(50)`. Instead, you could ensure that you call method `addImage` asynchronously, e.g.

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
   CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::addImage);
}
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add 10")) {
   CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> addImages(10));
}
```

with

```
  private void addImages(int numberOfImages) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
      addImage();
      startAnimation();
    }
  }
```

If you want to experiment a bit more with threads, then you can think about how to do it "by hand".

Comment: I still have a small problem though. When I use the "Add10" button and the newly created addImages() function gets activated after I pause the program the AnimationThread is canceled, but this function is still running so even after I reset it still creates the images. I know I can assign a completableFuture to a CompletableFuture returned by the runAsync. I noticed that it has a function .cancel() and i put it in a restart button action listener but still the same thing happens. I press stop while the addImages function is still running and after i hit restart images still appear

Comment: To really make it work smooth, there is some way to go. Some recommendations: make `imageList` thread safe, e.g. by using `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());` upon creation and then guard it by `synchronized (imageList)` blocks as documented in docu of ``Collections.synchronizedList`. In addition `undoMove` seems not to be enough if you add some new 10 of pics into the game. (Try to hit Add 10) twice fast and the images will get stuck. When catching `InterruptedException` think about interrupting the current thread by `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` Have fun learning! :-D

Comment: While im not sure if all I did with the synchronizing is right, but it doesn't seem to work. Tbh i'm not really sure how to use all the synchronizing stuff. Do you think you could show me how to use it in some parts of my code? It would be great if I saw an example on a piece of code I understand :D

Comment: Maybe you could start a new question for concurrency related topics. I think it is valuable to get fresh input.